# Multivariable calculus - Conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have vector field $\vec{F}=(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}),(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$

And the domains

$D_1=\{(x,y):4\leq x^2+y^2\leq 9, y\geq 0\}$

$D_2=\{(x,y):4\leq x^2+y^2\leq 9, y\leq 0\}$

$D_3= D_1\cup  D_2$

Now the vector field is conservative in $D_1$ and $D_2$ but not $D_3$

Why is that?

Comment: Learn what "simply connected" means.

Comment: To show that $\vec F$ is conservative in $D_1$, you can find a potential for $\vec F$ in $D_1$. A possible choice is $\arg(x + i y)$ with $-\pi/2 < \arg z < 3 \pi/2$. Or, since $D_1$ is simply connected, you can verify that $\nabla \times \vec F = 0$. To show that $\vec F$ is not conservative in $D_3$, you can find a closed curve the integral over which is not zero (take a circle centered at the origin). Path independence and existence of a potential are equivalent, regardless of whether or not the domain is simply connected.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, because $\;D_1\cup D_2\;$ isn't simply connected: it "wraps" around $\;(0,0)\;$ and the field isn't even defined at this point. In each of $\;D_1,\,D_2\;$ it is just fine...

Comment: but its like theres a hole circle inside the big circle so either ways (0,0) isnt defined

Comment: @LightLamps True, but you can then draw a closed, simple curve in $\;D_1\cup D_2\;$ s.t. that such curce will go around $\;(0,0)\;$ ...! You couldn't do this with $\;D_1\;$ or $\;D_2\;$ alone...

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Find a closed path in $D_3$ whose line integral is non-zero.

**Step 2.** If then you remove $D_2$ from the domain, what happens to the path you found in Step 1?